# What is "colptr" in Julia and its counterpart in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, julia

I'm trying to rewrite some Julia code into python code. And I just found `colptr` attached to sparse matrix. I searched it but I still don't understand what it is.
Could someone provide me the information about it and counterpart in python 3? Thank you in advance.

[edit]
this is from [Julia's references](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/SparseArrays/)

```
struct SparseMatrixCSC{Tv,Ti<:Integer} <: AbstractSparseMatrix{Tv,Ti}
m::Int                  # Number of rows
n::Int                  # Number of columns
colptr::Vector{Ti}      # Column j is in colptr[j]:(colptr[j+1]-1)
rowval::Vector{Ti}      # Row indices of stored values
nzval::Vector{Tv}       # Stored values, typically nonzeros
```

for instance, `A.colptr[j]` is referring all the elements of j-th column of CSC matrix `A`?

I tried to figure it out by running some simple code below,

```
A = sparse([1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 0])

for i=1:4
    println(A.colptr[i])
end
```

and the result was

> 1
> 2
> 3
> 5

I still have no idea why the result would be like this. explanation says

> Ti is the integer type for storing column pointers

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared what came up in your research and what didn't make sense about it. That way, people don't waste time recommending resources you've already exhausted

Comment: You might want to start by clarifying what counterpart of CSC matrix you have chosen. "Pointer to column" largely depends on what the column even is, and that largely depends on what the matrix is.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to focus on one issue? Are you trying to understand what ``colptr`` represents, *or* what it's Python equivalent is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking at a compressed sparse column (CSC) representation of a matrix. Instead of, for example, storing *all* the values of a matrix in sequence in memory, this allows only storing nonzero values.  For example, the matrix

```
5  0  0
6  0  7
1  0  3
0  2  0
```

can *either* be stored in memory as the column major sequence `5  6  1  0  0  0  0  2  0  7  3  0` *or* you could do something smarter.

If you only store the column major sequence of nonzero elements, you end up with a much shorter list: `5  6  1  2  7  3`!  But now you need a way to map these values back to their locations in the matrix.  You need a *column* index and a *row* index.  Thus, we have two more lists:

The row indices for each stored value can also be stored in a one-to-one fashion: `1  2  3  4  2  3`.

Now, I could store the column indices in a similar one-to-one fashion: `1 1 1 2 3 3`.  Were I to do so, this would be a sparse coordinate (COO) format.  But note that there's a lot of redundant information here: look at all those repeated values!  The common CSC format compresses this further.  I already know I have three columns; I could simply store *where* each column starts.  This is the `colptr`: it has one value per column and *points* to where that column starts.  Thus instead of storing six values, it only need to store three: column one starts at index one (of course). Column two starts at index 4, and column three starts at index 5.  It turns out to make life a bit easier if we also store a final fourth value representing one past the end, because then we can describe the nonzero values in a particular column simply by saying that the *stored values* in column `j` can be found in `nzval[colptr[j]:colptr[j+1]-1]`.

The typical Python equivalent is in scipy: [`scipy.sparse.csc_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html); simply substitutue `colptr` -> `indptr`, `indices` -> `rowval`, `nzval` -> `data` and accommodate the 0-based indexing.

Comment: I am confused why Column three does not start at index 2 instead?

Comment: @Shing why do you think it should?  My explanation is — excepting the final paragraph — in Julia terms, which has one-based indices.